# Onclick in xml by include

Tags: android, xml, onclick, include

In my project,I user onclick directly in the xml to assign a onclick methond to a button,it worked in my activityA, but when i have an activityB which setcontentview with a xml using  the xml which contains the "onclick" **and add the same onclick function in my activityB**,it does not work in the activityB.

What should I do to make it work?
Maybe find the button using findviewbyid and asign a new onclick to it work,but is there a more direct way to do this?

Comment: add the function handling onClick in activityA in your activityB

Comment: Sorry I have not mentioned that I have the same function handling on click in my activityB.

Comment: can you please add some source code to help us answering your request ?

Answer (score 1):

the `onClick` of activityA will not work for the button clicked in activityB..you'll have to again write the code of `onClick` in activityB..